# reading in specific columns from a text file

Tags: c++

I'm working with someone else's code and don't have a lot of c++ experience. I need to either edit the code to read in columns 2,3,4 and not 1 or 5, or change it to read CSV files instead of txt files. Here's the current read in code:

```
fin.getline(temp,200);

cout << temp << end1;

sscanf(temp, "%f %f %f %*f\n",&temp1,&temp2,&temp3);
```

This code works to read in older txt files as they didn't have the column one I'm trying to exclude.
Is it something simple like adding another `%*`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and still reasonable way is to change your line to:

```
sscanf(temp, "%f %f %f %f %*f\n",&unused, &temp1,&temp2,&temp3);
```

First col value goes to 'unused' and all after 4th is skipped.

Also you may need to increase size od 'temp'.

Adding %*f, at the beginning should also do the job, but I hadn't use it for some time, and don't have possibility to check now, but both solutions looks ok.

Comment: No problem, if it did mark this qestion as solved :)